# Javascript appendchild doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have the following simple code where I try to create a `div` inside another `div` using `appendChild`.

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector('div')
let div2 = document.createElement('DIV')
div1.appendChild(div2)
for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  div1.textContent += "Text "
  if (x <= 30) {
    div2.textContent += 'Yes '
  }
}

console.log(div1)
console.log(div2)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I am not sure why this code doesn't working. The `div` has already been created but just not appending to the `div1`.

Could anyone explain me what is wrong with the appendChild? I think there is no syntax problem with `appendChild`

Thanks for any responds!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `appendChild` at all. Read the documentation on [`textContent`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent): _“Warning: Setting `textContent` on a node removes all of the node’s children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value.”_

Comment: Also note that `div2` still exists, it's just no longer in the DOM. Re-append it after your for-loop.

Comment: Consider `document.querySelector("div").append(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), { textContent: "Yes ".repeat(31) }), "Text ".repeat(100));`. Is this what you were after?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, thank for pointing out my error. I have read the documentation. Thank you! Also, the code you provided is the effect I want to trigger. Thanks!

Comment: @connexo thank you for pointing out my error!